# Item click масива с выводами свойств?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я хочу организовать метод - кликаем на item массива и получаем в консоле его свойства
Пример массива прикреплю
Клик происходить конечно же на страннице (массива который отрендерен)

1. Рендер массив - 2) Клик - выдим в консоле 3 поля (т на что кликнули)

   ```
    "seats": [
    [
        {
            "number": 13345,
            "type": "mark",
            "status": "false",
        },
        {
            "number": 92225,
            "type": "peer",
            "status": "false",
        },
        {
            "number": 94245,
            "type": "mark",
            "status": "false",
        },
        {
            "number": 12345,
            "type": "mark",
            "status": "true",
    }
    ]
   ]
   ```

Результат клика - выдим в консоле

```
{
        "number": 12345,
        "type": "mark",
        "status": "true",
}
```

Comment: Cтало интересно мнения человека который думаю это мой вопрос есть некоректный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный у вас массив объектов, получается массив в массиве)

В таком случае, обратитесь к массиву по индексу 0, чтобы вывести объекты в виде, допустим, списка:

```
<li v-for="item in seats[0]" @click="getItem(item)">
```

и соответственно метод, который будет "заносить" значение выбранного объекта в переменную `activeItem` `getItem(item)` (для вывода в консоль этого не обязательно):

```
getItem(item) {
  this.active = item
},
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeItem: null,
    seats: [[{
      "number": 13345,
      "type": "mark",
      "status": "false",
    }, {
      "number": 92225,
      "type": "peer",
      "status": "false",
    }, {
      "number": 94245,
      "type": "mark",
      "status": "false",
    }, {
      "number": 12345,
      "type": "mark",
      "status": "true",
    }]]
  },
  methods: {
    getItem(item) {
      this.activeItem = item
      console.clear()
      console.log(item)
    },
  },
})
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul v-if="seats.length">
    <li v-for="item in seats[0]" @click="getItem(item)">
      {{ item.type }} {{ item.number }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <template v-if="activeItem">
    <h4>Выбранная запись</h4><pre>{{ JSON.stringify(activeItem, 0 ,2) }}</pre>
  </template>
  <template v-else>
    Кликните на любой пункт списка
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо я уже решил ) делал for в for )